# Opening and reading file in python

Tags: python, split, scope, text-files, indentation

I am having trouble with opening and reading a file writing python. I am supposed to read values from a .txt file in order to find the maximum, minimum etc.. When I create and array inside the code, like "values = [1, 5, 77]" for example, it works fine. But when I try to open the .txt file, which is in the same map as my .py file, i get errors. Someone help me please!

```
from statistics import median

max_value = None
min_value = None
avg_value = None
med_value = None

#values = [10, 0, 50, 99, -200, 1313, 7]

#with open("varden.txt") as values:
#   for line in values:
#       print (line)

#values = open("varden.txt", "r")
#   file = values.readlines().split()

with open('varden.txt') as f:
   values = f.readlines().split()

#       max_value = values[0]
            for number in values:
                if number>max_value:
                    max_value = number

#       min_value = values[0]
            for number in values:
                if number<min_value:
                    min_value = number


avg_value = sum(values)/len(values)
med_value = median(values)

values.close()

print ("Maximum value is: ", max_value)
print ("Minimum value is: ", min_value)
print ("Avarage value is: ", avg_value)
print ("Median value is: ", med_value)
```

[Screenshot of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mehfx.png)

Errors:

```
  File "laboration1del2.py", line 21
  for number in values:
                      ^
  TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation
```

Comment: What errors? Please, always provide every error with full traceback, otherwise we won't be able to guess your problem

Comment: Something is wrong with the formatting of your code, the indentation make no sense to me.

Regaring your problem: You've got two things going on. Python distinguishes between numbers and strings, so when you use `readlines()`, you get strings instead of numbers. Also, `readlines().split()` won't work because `readlines()` produces a list.

Answer (score 2):

> File "laboration1del2.py", line 21 for number in values: ^ TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation

^If this is your error, then it is likely referring to your loops which appear to be indented too much. Python depends on formatting, en lieu of something like braces, to interpret code and define scope.

Playing with your posted code, it looks like your loops had too many indents, and also your **values** variable appears to have 3 spaces indenting it, which seems odd. I've seen tabs generally represented as 4 spaces or 2 spaces, but never 3.

Try this code below:

```
with open('varden.txt') as f:
    values = f.readlines().split()

    for number in values:
        if number>max_value:
            max_value = number


    for number in values:
        if number<min_value:
            min_value = number
```

EDIT: You're also declaring  **values** within your **with open()** block. As a result, I don't think you're going to be able to access it outside of that like you currently are. When that gives you trouble, you're going to be looking to indent these lines as well. so that they are within the scope of that **with open()** block you've got going on

```
avg_value = sum(values)/len(values)
med_value = median(values)

values.close()
```

Comment: Should I just remove the indentions at the loops then?

Comment: @OssianLundberg Try replacing the block in question with the code I've added in my edit.

Comment: When I do this i get: "values = f.readlines().split()
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'". When I erase ".split()" I get: "if number>max_value:
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'NoneType'"

Comment: @OssianLundberg I don't want to come off rude here, and I'd like to see you get your problem solved, but I have to point this out: All of these errors are telling you exactly what is wrong. I would suggest you start researching each of these individual errors to better understand what you're doing wrong. I think in the long run, you'll be better off as a coder if you understand why you're getting each of these.

Comment: I do agree with you, its just that I learn much better from other people compared to googling. I will do that though, thanks for taking time!

Comment: @OssianLundberg I understand, and thank you. Did you get the code up and running?

Answer (score 0):

One issue which I can see in the line `values = f.readlines().split()` as `readlines()` returns a list and you are applying `split()` on a list which is not possible.

Try the below one once, 
`values = f.readlines()[0].split('=')[1].strip() // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]`

Comment: I get this error when using that: "values = f.readlines()[0].split('=')[1].strip()
IndexError: list index out of range"

Comment: I am assuming your text file contains only `values = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]`